# Binary representations of the cp1252 encoded characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, cp1252

Where can I find the binary representations of the characters encapsulated within the cp1252 character library for Windows(e.g. •, †, …, etc.)?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)? I guess that doesn't show binary equivalents, but you could just convert the decimal codes to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in `Lib/encodings/cp1252.py`

It was generated from ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT